# Python-telegram-bot || TypeError: register() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'

Tags: python, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am developing a python-telegram-bot but I am facing this issue...

```
@run_async
def register(bot, update, args):
    if update.message.chat_id < 0:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Use PM", parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
        return
    # user data
    user_username = update.effective_user.username
    user_chatid = update.message.chat_id
    user_firstname = update.message.from_user.first_name
    try:
        channel_data = args[0]
    except IndexError as e:
        update.message.reply_text("Please enter your Channel details!!")
        return

    # filter for avoid spammer
    if len(channel_data) > 500:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Please do not Spam in the bot!", parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
        return

    # check same data:

    # send user data to users_data
    user_data[str(user_chatid)] = {"user_firstname": str(user_firstname), "user_username": user_username, "channel_data": channel_data}

    # make report message about user's biodata
    msg  = "Registered by: " + user_firstname + "\n"
    msg += "@" + user_username + "\n"
    msg += "Channel details: \n" + channel_data + "\n"

    print(user_data)
    print("\n")
    print(msg)

    # send message to user
    bot.send_message(chat_id=293125876, text=msg)
```

THIS ^^^ is the code for what I am struggling.
The error is:

```
<bot_name>   v1  : Started Succesfully!
2018-09-05 09:45:16,764 - telegram.utils.promise - ERROR - An uncaught error was raised while running the promise
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\promise.py", line 57, in run
    self._result = self.pooled_function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: register() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'
```

The functions like /start /help works fine!
But this command above when used gives this error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: How are you calling the `register` function originally?

Comment: Did you mean `*args` and not `args`?

Comment: Hello @Karl  - The problem is solved, Only PYCHARM IDE gives the error. I ran same code using CMD as Terminal and it ran succesfully..

Comment: No @MikhailBurshteyn its `args` ... the error is still occuring pls help

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `pass_args=True` to CommandHandler arguments? If not, it should look like that:

```
register_handler = CommandHandler('register', register, pass_args=True)
```